# Why can't I treat an array like a pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference, memory-address

I see this question a lot on SO. Maybe not in so many words... but time and again there is confusion on how arrays are different from pointers. So I thought I would take a moment to Q&A a few points about this.

For purposes of this Q&A we're going to assume a 32-bit system and the following have been declared:

```
char * ptr = "hello";
char arr[10] = "hello";
int iarr[10] = {0};
```

Here's a list of questions that surmise the confusion I see on SO. As I see new ones I'll add to my list of Q&A (others feel free to as well, and correct me if you see any mistakes!)

1. Isn't a pointer and an array basically the same thing?
2. Follow up: both `*(ptr)` and `*(arr)`, or `ptr[0]` and `arr[0]` give the same thing, why?
3. How come `arr` and `&arr` is the same value?
4. Follow up: why do I get a different value printing `arr+1` vs `&arr+1`?

Comment: @Prætorian - That is absolutely a great link, the only reason why I was considering this to be separate was that is C++ specific. I was targeting this at C (hence the tag) and at the new programmers, I didn't want to confuse things with the templates and differences between C++ and C.

Comment: Comments on the downvotes please. I'm happy to clean things up but let's discuss what you don't like! Thanks.

Comment: You are missing half the picture. The only things you consider are _statically_ declared arrays. There is another kind; _dynamically_ declared arrays. These are the kinds of arrays that are declared with a variable expression as a size parameter, and also the kind that are passed into functions. Dynamically declared arrays also behave like pointers when using the `&` operator and the `sizeof()` function. It is also worth noting that when you pass a static array into a function, it is converted to a dynamic array, or in other words, the address is copied into a pointer.

Comment: @Zistack: Dynamic arrays are a conceptual thing, and have no language aspect thought.  Dynamic arrays are considered to be pointers at the language level.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) **Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers.** Don't think of them that way because they are different.
How can I prove this? Think about what they look like in memory:

Our array `arr` is 10 characters long. It contains "Hello", but wait, that's not all! Because we have a statically declared array longer than our message, we get a bunch of NULL characters (`'\0'`) thrown in for free! Also, note how the name `arr` is conceptually attached to the contiguous characters, (it's not pointing to anything).
[image]

Next consider how our pointer would look in memory:
[image]
Note here we're pointing to a character array some place in read only memory.

So while both `arr` and `ptr` were initialized the same way, the contents/location of each is actually different.

**This is the key point:**
**ptr** is a variable, we can point it to anything, **arr** is a constant, it will always refer to this block of 10 characters.

---

2) The `[]` is an "add and deference" operator that can be used on an address. Meaning that `arr[0]` is the same as saying `*(arr+0)`. So yes doing this:

```
printf("%c %c", *(arr+1), *(ptr+1));
```

Would give you an output of "e e". It's not because arrays are pointers, it's because the name of an array `arr` and a pointer `ptr` both happen to give you an address.

**Key point to #2:** The deference operator `*` and the add and deference operator `[]` are not specific to pointers and arrays respectively. These operators simply work on addresses.

---

3)  I don't have an extremely simple answer... so let's forget our character arrays for a second and take a look at it this example for an explanation:

```
int b;   //this is integer type
&b;      //this is the address of the int b, right?

int c[]; //this is the array of ints
&c;      //this would be the address of the array, right?
```

So that's pretty understandable how about this:

```
*c;   //that's the first element in the array
```

What does that line of code tell you? If I deference `c`, then I get an int. That means just plain `c` is an address. Since it's the start of the array it's the address of the array and also the address of the first element in the array, thus from a value standpoint:

```
c == &c;
```

---

4) Let me go off topic for a second here... this last question is part of the confusion of address arithmetic. I saw a question on SO at one point implying that addresses are just integer values... You need to understand that in C addresses have knowledge of type. That is to say:

```
iarr+1; //We added 1 to the address, so we moved 4 bytes
arr+1;  //we added 1 to the address, so we moved 1 byte
```

Basically the `sizeof(int)` is 4 and the `sizeof(char)` is 1. So "adding 1 to an array" is not as simple as it looks.

So now, back to the question, why is `arr+1` different from `&arr+1`? The first one is adding `1 * sizeof(char)`=1 to the address, the second one is adding `1 * sizeof(arr)`=10 to the address.

This is why even though they are both "only adding 1" they give different results.

Comment: How does your answer to Q4 relate to Q4?

Comment: "This is why `ptr` is considered an lvalue". No, that's not why `ptr` is considered to be an _lvalue_; after all `arr` is also considered to be an _lvalue_.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I rewrote the Q&A4 a tiny bit. Does that help show how they relate? Just wanted to make it clear that +1 on an address isn't always the same (depending on what type the address is)

Comment: It's the Q that needs to be changed. Have a read of Q4 again.

Comment: @CharlesBailey - Thanks for your input. `arr` is indeed a "named region of storage" (definition of an lvalue). But is it not considered a "unmodifiable lvalue" since the location where the first element will be stored can't be changed once `arr` is declared? Is my understanding incorrect, or is it the way I phrased things that you disagree with?

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand why you are evening mentioning _lvalue_. `arr` and `ptr` are both _lvalues_ but so is every expression that is an identifier denoting a variable or reference. It just doesn't seem to be relevant to the pointer vs array discussion.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Many people still believe that *lvalue* means *can stand on the left of an assignment*.

Comment: @FredOverflow: ...and perpetuating that understanding is not helpful. (IMHO)

Comment: @CharlesBailey - Your point is taken, I removed the line in question as it doesn't really add value. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned alredy, sizeof() gets a bit more tricky when arr is passed into a function. I think the array/pointer thing in C is one of those topics that only experience can turn them into some kind of "muscle memory". So practice, practice, practice :) Btw, in many cases it comes down to length vs size, and a safe rule of thumb is to always pass whichever you need along with the array in a function (or provide a safe alternative, like a sentinel value at the end of the array).