# C Pointers and Arrays Incompatible Types

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

So I was wondering why I can't do this.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *src;
    char filePath[261];
    filePath = argv[1];
```

The last line is where there is a compiler error. What's the difference between char[] and char*? How would I fix this code so I can set filePath equal to argv[1].
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable values, nor are they pointers.

Comment: This is the difference between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676402/why-cant-i-treat-an-array-like-a-pointer-in-c/12676404#12676404

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
strcpy(filePath, argv[1]);
```

and live happy.  Don't forget to check argv[1] for being NULL and don't forget to see if argc is > 1.

Your `filePath` variable is a fixed-size array which is allocated on the stack and argv[i] is a pointer to some memory in the heap. Assigning to filePath cannot be done, because filePath is not a pointer, it is the data itself.

Answer (score 2):

Because `filePath` is an array and it's not allowed to modify the address of an array in C.
You can use the [string family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/string) to copy the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have:

```
FILE *src;
char *filePath;
filePath = argv[1];
```

since `filePath` must *point* to argv, not to an array of 261 bytes. If you want, you can *copy* the argumenti into the array:

```
FILE *src;
char filePath[261];
strcpy(filePath, argv[1]);
```

or better, to avoid risking copying more bytes than you have available (which would result in disaster):

```
FILE *src;
char filePath[261];
strncpy(filePath, argv[1], sizeof(filePath));
```

or again

```
#define MAX_FILESIZE    261

FILE *src;
char filePath[MAX_FILESIZE];
strncpy(filePath, argv[1], MAX_FILESIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: What's the difference between char[] and char*?

A: Often times, you can use them interchangeably.

But here, you're "attempting to use an array name as an lvalue" :)

Here's a good explanation:

- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/

Here's a short summary of "what's legal, and what's not":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx